# Change output using a .jsx script for After Effects CS6

Tags: video, after-effects, file-formats

I've made a script that will loop through a (.txt) interchanging elements of a certain composition.

Within the script, I add each changed composition to the render queue and output it.

How can I pragmatically output the format in h.264 (.mp4) instead of it defaulting to (.avi).

I've discovered that you can just change the default output module via edit -> templates -> output module, but still.. is there anyway of doing this via script?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the answer to your question is 'yes, but...'

It's perfectly feasible, but you have to create an output module with the settings that you want, and then save it to your computer.  You can create this by going to Edit -> Templates -> Output Module.  Click on the 'New' button in the pop-up window, and then Edit it for the settings you need (quicktime, h.264, etc).  Save it as a useful name ("H264HighQuality" or something like that).  Save the output module, and you'll be able to access it from your scripts from there on out.

In order to use it in your script, just use:
`app.project.renderQueue.items.add(myComp).applyTemplate("H264HighQuality");`

As long as you've *made* the template first, you can access it in your scripts as many times as you want.  However, After Effects does NOT allow you to programmatically create Output Modules or alter them on the fly, unfortunately.  But you only need to make the template once -- as long as you have that template on the computer you're running the script, it should work just fine.

Comment: This answers my question. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2):

To update @MBrizzle answer, this functionality was added to After Effects CC 2014. There are 4 new methods:

- RenderQueueItem object getSetting, setSetting methods
- OutputModule object getSetting, setSetting methods

You can find more about them at http://blogs.adobe.com/aftereffects/2014/04/new-changed-after-effects-cc-2014.html

Comment: To update your answer Output Module setSetting only allow these keys: Audio Bit Depth
Audio Channels
Audio Sample Rate
Channels :
Color : Premultiplied (Matted)
Crop : false
Crop Bottom
Crop Left
Crop Right
Crop Top : 0
Depth : Millions of Colors
Format : QuickTime
Include Project Link : true
Include Source XMP Metadata : false
Lock Aspect Ratio : true
Output Audio : Auto
Output File Info : [object Object]
Post-Render Action : 
Resize : false
Resize Quality : High
Resize to : HDV/HDTV 720 25
Starting #
Use Comp Frame Number
Use Region of Interest
Video Output

Comment: No codecs allowed